# How do I undo "svn switch" on a subdirectory?

Tags: svn

Not for the first time, I've accidentally done "svn switch" from somewhere below the root of my project. This switches that subdirectory only, but how do I undo this?

If I try switching the subdirectory back to the original branch I get:

```
"svn: Directory 'subdir\_svn' containing working copy admin area is missing"
```

**Update**: I've got changes in the subdir, so I don't want to do a delete.

In the short term I've fixed it by reapplying the changes, but I was after a way to get Subversion to re-switch back to where I came from... or is this a missing feature?

Answer (score 7):

Quick hack: Delete the directory, go one level up, and run svn update.

Comment: You can make a patch, do rm/svn up, and reapply the patch.

Comment: I hate svn. So much. It takes me a day of switching, updating, massaging, deleting and then switching a few times more to get a clean switch.

Comment: I have the folder already removed from the repo, while locally it's `S`. When I `rm -rf; cd ..; svn up`, it restores! ..(

Comment: Instead of deleting the directory in question, you can simply rename it. This way, you won't lose all the non-versioned files within it (e.g., uploaded files, etc). Once you fix the svn problems with an svn up or svn switch, you can copy the non-versioned files back into the appropriate directory.

Comment: Deleting just the switched directory did not work. I had to delete its superfolder.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing exactly how you did the switch and how your directory and repository layout is, it's hard to say what went wrong in your case.

There is no way to really "revert" a switch. Generally, svn switch can be undone by a switch back to the original location, i.e. when the original location is at svn://url/to/orig/dir, then the following should work:

Switching a subdirectory to a different part of the repository

```
svn switch svn://path/to/switched/dir/ subdir
```

... and switching it back again

```
svn switch svn://url/to/orig/dir subdir
```

In your case it sounds as if you tried to switch a directory that is not part of your working copy.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by checking in the changes in the switched directory, deleting the .svn files and the misplaced files, then using `svn checkout <rootUrl>` followed by `svn update -r HEAD --force`.

I don't think there's a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

if the latest changes are just the switch then,

Right click on common parent directory, tortoise svn->
Go to svn logs. Right click on version before SVN Switch and select Revert to this revision.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it works to run another switch back to the the proper path to the directory you are actually in. That is, if you ran:

```
svn switch file:///srv/svn/someproject/branch/27
```

while you were in someproject/subdir, then run

```
svn switch file:///srv/svn/someproject/branch/26/subdir
```

and then run your original switch from the correct place.

This seems to restore order.

Answer (score 0):

My use case seemed simple; I wanted to switch back to the directory with the current directory's name rooted at the parent directory's URL. The hassle here, of course, is getting and then copying the parent directory's URL. This script in Windows batch did it for me. Bash users can do it much more easily but the gist is here. It seems like this functionality would be trivial to fold into SVN directly...

You may need to add quotes around the parameter to switch but I'll leave that to you. In case it's not obvious, you need to run this in the directory that you want to "unswitch". It doesn't take parameters or anything at this time although that's a pretty straight forward addition should you be so inclined (just `cd \d %1` at the top if `%1` isn't empty).

**svn-unswitch.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=*" %%u in ('svn info --show-item url ..') do set "PARENT_URL=%%u"
call :SetDirName %CD%
svn switch %PARENT_URL%/%DIRNAME%
goto :eof

:SetDirName
    set DIRNAME=%~nx1
    goto :eof
```

Certified: *Works On My Machine!*

Answer (score -2):

```
svn revert <dir>
```

Or, yes, delete it and grab another copy.

Comment: `svn revert <dir>`does not revert the switch. It reverts local modifications (if any), but still keeps the content of the switched substree.